# User defined password at registration - registration email sends auto generated pass

Tags: user-registration, user-meta, password

Updating some meta fields on registration and providing the user the option to pick a password yet the registration email sends the auto generated password. User defined password works and not emailed pass.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'jwh_register_extra_fields', 100 );
function jwh_register_extra_fields( $user_id, $password = '', $meta = array() )  {
$userdata = array();

$userdata['ID'] = $user_id;
if ( $_POST['password'] !== '' ) {
    $userdata['user_pass'] = $_POST['password'];
}

$userdata['first_name'] = $_POST['first_name'];
$userdata['last_name'] = $_POST['last_name'];
$userdata['user_url'] = $_POST['user_url'];

$new_user_id = wp_update_user( $userdata );
}
```

Comment: Mate you need to clerify you question. Are you talking about registration with custom password or changing password after user is already registered.

Comment: Yep. Registration works and custom password is stored but the welcome email from WordPress sends the auto generated pass.

Comment: but this function updated user information and is not used for registration... is this the function you are trying to use to register new user or just to update the user infromation???

Comment: Ahh. Ok. to it fires AFTER registration. How do I hook in earlier during registration?

Comment: sorry to open a mini chat here - i just dont get where you get the $user_id value from?  if it a new user registration there is no user id yet... (i just dont want to misslead you with the wrong answer)  - Should i just dissregard your function and give you a way to register a new member to your site?

Comment: @Andrew Bartel cut the chitchat and gave your the complete way :) - (+1 @andrew).

Comment: Thanks, didn't mean to hijack your thread or anything I just did this the other day for a client site so.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to WPSE.  You can use [wp_insert_user](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user), you don't need to hook onto anything.

Assuming here they fill out a form with a name, username, email and password field, and you capture it however you want.

```
$name_array = explode(' ',$_POST['name']);
$user = array(
    'user_login' => $_POST['username'],
    'user_pass' => $_POST['password'],
    'user_email' => $_POST['email'],
    'first_name' => $name_array[0],
    'last_name' => $name_array[1],
            );
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $user );

wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $_POST['password'] );
```

Comment: I still get the auto generated pass.

Comment: I just ran it again, i got my entered password, are you sure you're passing the second parameter to wp_new_user_notification?  And you're using your own form right, not the stand wp registration form?

Comment: Oops. Typo in form action. This works, but it's nice having WP do all the checking wether a username exists and other validation.

Comment: So would you consider this code safe? How do you know that POST data is safe(and set) prior to the user insertion?

Comment: No, I don't consider it safe.  @t31os I'd really love your input on this question: http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2472/completeness-of-answers

Comment: You could use `esc_attr()` and [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.filter-var.php) to get on the **safe** side. For the later function, you got constants that even allow you filter for valid email strings.